# PHP - Differences between `get_headers` and `stream_get_meta_data`?

Tags: php, get-headers

### Intro / Disclaimer

Decent chunks of this are outputs that can largely be ignored. It is still a bit of a reader, but I'm trying to be thorough in my analysis and questioning. ***If you are familiar with `stream_get_meta_data`, you would be fine to skip to the "Questions" at the end***.

Other than in the DOCs, I am having trouble finding out much about PHP's [`stream_get_meta_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php). The overall functionality is not vastly different to that of PHP's [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), but I cannot for the life of me find any comparisons between the two, or pros/cons of the former.

### The Setup

Up until this point, I've always used PHP's `get_headers` to verify the validity of a URL. The downside with `get_headers` is that it is [notoriously slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964223/something-faster-than-get-headers). Understandably, much of the latency is directly due to the server hosting the site of interest, but *maybe* the method is just overly robust, or something else is slowing it down.

There are plenty of links that recommend using `CURL`, claiming that it is faster, but I've run side-by-side, timed tests of both, and `get_headers` has always come out on top, often by a factor of 1.5 or 2.

I've yet to see any solutions using `stream_get_meta_data`, and only just stumbled upon it for the first time today. I've exhausted my Google skills, without much luck. But, in the interest of optimizing my scheme, I ran some tests.

### The Testing

Comparisons between `get_headers` and `stream_get_meta_data` were run using a list of 106 current (i.e. live, valid, status=200) URLs:

***`Code Block #1`***

```
// All URLs in format "http://www.domain.com"
$urls = array('...', '...', '...'); // *106 URLs

// get_headers
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($urls as $url) {
    try{
        // Unfortunately, get_headers does not offer a context argument
        stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "HEAD")));
        $headers[] = @get_headers($url, 1); 
        stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => "GET")));

    }catch(Exception $e){
        continue;
    }
}
$end1 = microtime(true) - $start;

// stream_get_meta_data
$cont = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => "HEAD")));
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($urls as $url) {
    try{
        $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $cont);
        if(!$fp) {
            continue;
        }
        $streams[] = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        continue;
    }
}
$end2 = microtime(true) - $start;
```

And the results I'm getting are `stream_get_meta_data` coming out on top, *90% of the time, or more*. Sometimes the times are nearly identical, but more often than not `stream_get_meta_data` has the shorter run-time

***`Run Times #1`***

```
"get_headers": 112.23 // seconds
"stream_get":  42.61 // seconds
```

With the [stringified] outputs of the two being something like:

***`Excerpt of Comparison #1`***

```
url  ..  "http://www.wired.com/"

get_headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
|    Access-Control-Allow-Origin  ..  "*"
|    Cache-Control  ................  "stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-while-error=86400"
|    Content-Type  .................  "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    Link  .........................  "; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\""
|    Server  .......................  "Apache"
|    Via
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    
|    Fastly-Debug-State  ...........  "HIT"
|    Fastly-Debug-Digest  ..........  "c245efbf14778c681ce317da114c1a762199e1326323d07b531d765e97fc8695"
|    Content-Length  ...............  "135495"
|    Accept-Ranges  ................  "bytes"
|    Date  .........................  "Tue, 23 Aug 2016 22:32:26 GMT"
|    Age  ..........................  "701"
|    Connection  ...................  "close"
|    X-Served-By  ..................  "cache-jfk8149-JFK, cache-den6024-DEN"
|    X-Cache  ......................  "HIT, HIT"
|    X-Cache-Hits  .................  "51, 1"
|    X-Timer  ......................  "S1471991546.459931,VS0,VE0"
|    Vary  .........................  "Accept-Encoding"

stream_get
|    wrapper_data
|    |    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
|    |    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
|    |    "Cache-Control: stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-while-error=86400"
|    |    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    |    "Link: ; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\""
|    |    "Server: Apache"
|    |    "Via: 1.1 varnish"
|    |    "Fastly-Debug-State: HIT"
|    |    "Fastly-Debug-Digest: c245efbf14778c681ce317da114c1a762199e1326323d07b531d765e97fc8695"
|    |    "Content-Length: 135495"
|    |    "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
|    |    "Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 22:32:26 GMT"
|    |    "Via: 1.1 varnish"
|    |    "Age: 701"
|    |    "Connection: close"
|    |    "X-Served-By: cache-jfk8149-JFK, cache-den6020-DEN"
|    |    "X-Cache: HIT, HIT"
|    |    "X-Cache-Hits: 51, 1"
|    |    "X-Timer: S1471991546.614958,VS0,VE0"
|    |    "Vary: Accept-Encoding"
|    
|    wrapper_type  .................  "http"
|    stream_type  ..................  "tcp_socket/ssl"
|    mode  .........................  "rb"
|    unread_bytes  .................  0
|    seekable  .....................  false
|    uri  ..........................  "http://www.wired.com/"
|    timed_out  ....................  false
|    blocked  ......................  true
|    eof  ..........................  false
```

For the most part, all the same data, with the exception that `stream_get_meta_data` doesn't offer any way to include keys for `wrapper_data`, without parsing through it manually.

Easy enough...

***`Code Block #2.1/2.2`***

```
$wd = $meta[$url]['wrapper_data'];
$wArr = wrapperToKeys($wd);
```

where...

```
function wrapperToKeys($wd) {
    $wArr = array();
    foreach($wd as $row) {
        $pos = strpos($row, ': '); // *Assuming* that all separated by ": " (Might be colon, without the space?)

        if($pos === false) {
            $wArr[] = $row;
        }else {
            // $pos, $key and $value can probably be done with one good preg_match
            $key = substr($row, 0, $pos);
            $value = substr($row, ($pos + 2));

            // If key doesn't exist, assign value
            if(empty($wArr[$key])) {            
                $wArr[$key] = $value;
            }

            // If key already points to an array, add value to array
            else if(is_array($wArr[$key])) {    
                $wArr[$key][] = $value;
            }

            // If key currently points to string, swap value into an array
            else {                          
                $wArr[$key] = array($wArr[$key], $value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $wArr;
}
```

And the output is *identical* to `get_headers($url, 1)`:

***`Excerpt of Comparison #2`***

```
url  ..  "http://www.wired.com/"

headers
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
|    Access-Control-Allow-Origin  ..  "*"
|    Cache-Control  ................  "stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-while-error=86400"
|    Content-Type  .................  "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    Link  .........................  "; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\""
|    Server  .......................  "Apache"
|    Via
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    
|    Fastly-Debug-State  ...........  "HIT"
|    Fastly-Debug-Digest  ..........  "c245efbf14778c681ce317da114c1a762199e1326323d07b531d765e97fc8695"
|    Content-Length  ...............  "135495"
|    Accept-Ranges  ................  "bytes"
|    Date  .........................  "Tue, 23 Aug 2016 22:35:29 GMT"
|    Age  ..........................  "883"
|    Connection  ...................  "close"
|    X-Served-By  ..................  "cache-jfk8149-JFK, cache-den6027-DEN"
|    X-Cache  ......................  "HIT, HIT"
|    X-Cache-Hits  .................  "51, 1"
|    X-Timer  ......................  "S1471991729.021214,VS0,VE0"
|    Vary  .........................  "Accept-Encoding"

w-arr
|    0  ............................  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
|    Access-Control-Allow-Origin  ..  "*"
|    Cache-Control  ................  "stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-while-error=86400"
|    Content-Type  .................  "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
|    Link  .........................  "; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\""
|    Server  .......................  "Apache"
|    Via
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    |    "1.1 varnish"
|    
|    Fastly-Debug-State  ...........  "HIT"
|    Fastly-Debug-Digest  ..........  "c245efbf14778c681ce317da114c1a762199e1326323d07b531d765e97fc8695"
|    Content-Length  ...............  "135495"
|    Accept-Ranges  ................  "bytes"
|    Date  .........................  "Tue, 23 Aug 2016 22:35:29 GMT"
|    Age  ..........................  "884"
|    Connection  ...................  "close"
|    X-Served-By  ..................  "cache-jfk8149-JFK, cache-den6021-DEN"
|    X-Cache  ......................  "HIT, HIT"
|    X-Cache-Hits  .................  "51, 1"
|    X-Timer  ......................  "S1471991729.173641,VS0,VE0"
|    Vary  .........................  "Accept-Encoding"
```

Even with sorting out the keys, `stream_get_meta_data`  is the champion:

***`Sample Run Times #2`***

```
"get_headers": 99.51 // seconds
"stream_get": 43.79 // seconds
```

*Note: These tests are being run on a cheap shared server - hence the large variations in testing times. That being said, the gap between the two methods is highly consistent between tests.*

### Additional

For those of you who understand the c-code for PHP, and feel they might be able to gain some insight from it, the function definitions can be found at:

['get_headers' (PHP Git)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/standard/url.c#L699)

and

['stream_get_meta_data' (PHP Git)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/standard/streamsfuncs.c#L491)

### Questions

1. How come `stream_get_meta_data` is so underrepresented (in searches and available code snippets) compared to `get_headers`?

   The way I've worded this leads to *opinions*, but my intent is more along the lines of: *"Is there something so well-known and terrible about `stream_get_meta_data` that tends to deter people from using it?"*
2. Similar to the previous, are there well-known, *industry agreed-upon* pros and cons between the two? The kinds of things that a more comprehensive understanding of CS would allude to. Perhaps `get_headers` is more secure/robust, and less susceptible to ne'erdowells and inconsistencies with server outputs? Or maybe `get_headers` is known to *work* in instances where `stream_get_meta_data` produces and error?

   From what I can find, `stream_get_meta_data` does have a couple [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php#refsect1-function.stream-get-meta-data-notes) and [warnings (... for fopen)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-notes), but nothing so awful that they can't be worked around.

So long as it is safe and consistent, I would like to incorporate it into my project, seeing as this operation is performed *often*, and cutting the run time in half would make a substantial difference.

### Edit #1

I have since found a few URLs that are successful with `get_headers` but throw a warning for `stream_get_meta_data`

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(http://www.alealimay.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

PHP Warning:  fopen(http://www.thelovelist.net/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

PHP Warning:  fopen(http://www.bleedingcool.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

`get_headers` returns only the `403 Forbidden` status, even though you can paste the URLs into a browser and see they are working sites.

Unsure about this: both the break-down of `stream_get_meta_data`, and the incomplete header from `get_headers` (should include all redirects and final `status_code = 200` for functioning sites).

---

*Much thanks, if you've made it this far.*

*Also, please comment if you down-vote, so I might be able to improve the question, and we can all learn for future cases.*

Comment: @PaulCrovella I'm disappointed I never thought to try, but you're right on the money. `stream_get = 85.79s` and `get_header = 40.55s` when flipped around. Will run a couple more to confirm, but I'd say it's about busted open. All things being equal then, I'll stick to `get_headers`. (Speaking of which, I don't suppose you're a [`get_headers` guru](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113450/php-get-headers-returns-400-bad-request-and-403-forbidden-for-valid-urls)??)