# Effective method to check whether a URL exists or not using PHP

Tags: php, performance, curl, url-validation, get-headers

I'm trying to validate Google indexed URLs for a given domain in real time to return the valid pages count. I tried using PHP **get_headers()** and **curl** method. But even for 50 URLs both methods are taking more than 1 minute.

Is there any other easy method I can use to check whether a URL exists or not? As I have to show the result in real time it should take few seconds only.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964223/something-faster-than-get-headers

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. I will try with parallel curl requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.get-headers.php) function

```
$headers = @get_headers($url);
$valid = $headers && $headers[0] != 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found';
```

Comment: I've already tried get_headers(). But it is too slow. I tried with a domain having 5000 URLs and it was loading for a long time to complete all URLs. I want to get the result in few seconds only